# Powershell If then statement not working. How to fix logic?

Tags: powershell, operators, equality-operator

I can't seem to get this 'if then' statement to work.  What am I doing wrong with this simple statement.

```
$checkUS = "false"

$usRegions =(Get-EC2Region) |Where -Property RegionName -Like -Value "us-*" |select RegionName | foreach {$_.RegionName}
$allregions=(Get-EC2Region).RegionName

If($checkUS = "true") {$Regions=$usRegions} Else {$Regions=$allregions}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Powershell, the `=` operator is used for assignment.

You need to use the `-eq` comparison operator when defining your IF condition.

**Wrong**

`If($checkUS = "true") ...`

**Correct**

`If($checkUS -eq "true") ...`

.

- The first part (the condition) need the comparison operators
- The second part of the statement is performing variable assignments and therefore the `=` sign is the good call here. `{$Regions=$usRegions} Else {$Regions=$allregions}`

**Reference**

[About Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7)

Comment: As an aside: In advanced usage, `=` can be useful in conditionals, namely _in combination_ with a logical test, to _assign the result of an expression to a variable for later use_. This is useful if the expression doesn't just yield `$true` or `$false` and therefore relies on PowerShell's [implicit to-Boolean coercion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Booleans). E.g., `if ($files = Get-ChildItem *.txt) { … }` uses `Get-ChildItem`'s output or lack thereof as an implicit Boolean test, while capturing the output in variable `$files`.